# Racket - Peg Solitaire cannot reach solution

Tags: racket

I am having issues with a Racket program I have to write. We are using the Intermediate Student with Lambda language, and can use anything included in that. My assignment is to make a form of Peg Solitaire that displays a solution as a slideshow once the program figures out the solution (This code was given in the instructions). My problem is that my program seems to either endlessly loop or it just is not able to find a pathway to the solution based on the board. We were given the function `(find-route initial-state neighbours solved?)` with this contract:

`find-route: X (X -> (listof X)) (X -> Bool) -> (anyof false (listof X))`

It will produces a sequence of states until the solution.

I am calling on it using this function:

`(define (solitaire board state solution)
  (find-route state (make-neighbours board) (make-solved? solution)))`

Where `make-neighbours` is a working function that produces every possible move in a given state (I have tested this function extensively, it doesn't appear to be the problem, but it is very long, so I am hesitant to copy/paste it). Additionally, `make-solved?` is also a working function that generates a function that determines if a given state is a solution.

I think the issue is in `solitaire` but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. If there's any extra information that you need let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out where the problem is.

I suggest that you insert a display in order to see how the algorithm progresses:

```
(define (solitaire board state solution)
  (begin
    (display (list board state solution))
    (newline)
    (find-route state (make-neighbours board) (make-solved? solution))))
```

Then study the output. You want to find the state where the algorithm gets stuck.

Comment: I run into the problem that `begin` is not defined. Is there a way I can write this display function in Intermediate Student with lambda?

Comment: Temporarily (just while you track down the problem) change the language to Advanced. When you have identified the problem, change the language back again.

Comment: I've fixed it. If you're curious as to what the problem was, it was `neighbours`. I had forgotten a condition for it to check. Thank you for your help anyways.